# Meat juices can they be saved for recooking meat?

Tags: meat

Can I keep the dripping and meat juices to cook with at a later date?

Comment: Define "later date"... Welcome to the site! Besides, your question probably already has an answer here: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! There is a lot of flavor in juices and drippings and they can be used at a later time for soups, gravies, stews, braising meats, etc. You will need to store it in the refrigerator or, for longer storage, in the freezer.